# export to excel in c# where first row and 4 columns are in string & rest is in integer

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void ibtnExport_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
 {
   try
       {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = createDataTable();
            dt.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
            ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook wbook = new ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook();
            wbook.Worksheets.Add(dt,lblStartDate.Text+"to"+lblEndDate.Text);
            // Prepare the response
            HttpResponse httpResponse = Response;
            httpResponse.Clear();
            httpResponse.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            //Provide you file name here
            httpResponse.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\""+lblStartDate.Text+"to"+lblEndDate.Text+".xlsx\"");
            string style = @"<style> .integermode {mso-number-format:General} </style>";
            Response.Write(style);
            // Flush the workbook to the Response.OutputStream
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                wbook.SaveAs(memoryStream);
                memoryStream.WriteTo(httpResponse.OutputStream);
                memoryStream.Close();
            }
            httpResponse.End();

        }

        catch
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Something went wrong..')</script>");
        }


    }
```

This is the code which i am using to export excel. Here the header is in string but the rest of the column is also in string, which I  will need to change into a number or integer for doing addition which is ha tic for the user to perform any action on it.

Please do help me to resolve this. If you need any other part of the code please ask.

**Edit:**
This is the createDataTable code:

```
    private DataTable createDataTable()
    {
        DataSet _ds = new DataSet();
        _ds = (DataSet)ViewState["DataSet"];
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ProjectID");
        dt.Columns.Add("Projects");
        dt.Columns.Add("Network");
        dt.Columns.Add("Activity");
        dt.Columns.Add("SOP");
        for (int i = 0; i < _ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(_ds.Tables[1].Rows[i]["Name"].ToString() + "(" + _ds.Tables[1].Rows[i]["SapCode"].ToString() + ")");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < _ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(_ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ProjectID"].ToString(), _ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["BaseProject"].ToString(), _ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ProjectName"].ToString(), _ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Network"].ToString(), _ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Activity"].ToString(), _ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SOP"].ToString());
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < _ds.Tables[2].Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if(dt.Columns.Contains(_ds.Tables[2].Rows[j]["EmployeeData"].ToString()))
                //if (dt.Columns[_ds.Tables[2].Rows[j]["EmployeeData"].ToString()].ColumnName!= null && dt.Columns[_ds.Tables[2].Rows[j]["EmployeeData"].ToString()].ColumnName.ToString() != "")
                {
                    if (dt.Rows[i]["ProjectID"].ToString() == _ds.Tables[2].Rows[j]["ProjectID"].ToString() && dt.Columns[_ds.Tables[2].Rows[j]["EmployeeData"].ToString()].ColumnName.ToString() == _ds.Tables[2].Rows[j]["EmployeeData"].ToString())
                    {
                        dt.Rows[i][_ds.Tables[2].Rows[j]["EmployeeData"].ToString()] = Convert.ToDouble(_ds.Tables[2].Rows[j]["Hourspent"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: What is your problem? Please refer on [ask]

Comment: thanks for the quick response  after exporting Excel cell value is in string but i want it in numeric

Comment: Why not just convert it like  ``int number = Int32.Parse(someString);``

Comment: The issue here is i think in your DataTable, is the column DataColumn of type `int`? I think you should show what is `createDataTable()` implementation.

Comment: could you please help from where i could submit it

Comment: You don't need to create a datatable. Simply get EPPlus from Nuget and use a List.